# Cycle through div elements

Tags: jquery, html

I want to cycle through div elements in a page using jQuery and change the html inside. However I don't want to use the same class for the div's, nor can I cycle through all the div's on a page. What is a way of looping through these div's without using classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to give class then give some other attribute by which you can identify those divs...

**example:**

```
<div data-attr='abc' ></div>     // let attribute is data-attr

// then identify those divs by that attribute.
$("div ['data-attr' = 'abc']").html("<span>hello</span>");
```

Comment: This, thank you. I would upvote if it were in my power

Answer (score 0):

**Option:1**
Atleast, name the first div and you can use jquery to cycle through the rest using the .next() method.

**Option:2**
Name the parent and use .each() method on it's child "div" to cycle through all the corresponding "div's".

But you should atleast name something, any siblings or parent or grand parent or some element that could relate to this one.